# How to copy data from desktop to Memgraph DB?

Tags: graph-databases, memgraphdb

I have a Memgraph on my desktop with a bund of data. I need that data on my laptop where I have another Memgraph running. How can I do that? Can I just copy the DB directory?

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, all database systems don’t like you messing around with their binary data storage whilst they are running.
Memgraph is no exception to that.

So, the destination database must be stopped before copying the data and restarted after the data is copied in order for it to correctly load the data.

The source database doesn’t necessarily need to be stopped, but that is an implementation detail and you risk losing any pending, unflushed data.
The recommendation is always to stop everything while copying the binary data.

If the data is copied into the same directory on the destination server (`/var/lib/memgraph`) and with the correct permissions, you don’t have to reconfigure anything.
Data (snapshots) directory is defined in Memgraph configuration under `--data-directory`. By default, the directory is located under `/var/lib/memgraph`.